# Can I add a due date in Trello when I create card?

Tags: trello

If I create a card in Trello that I know the due date for, I have to first create the card and then click on card and enter due date.

Not a big deal, but was wondering if I was missing some shortcut which would allow me to create a card and assign a due date in one step.  For example, some other apps, like RememberTheMilk, automatically recognize a date entered in the description as a due date, so a new item can be created with a due date initially.

Can I do something similar in Trello to save a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem possible at the moment.

You can add due date from the board view, by selecting the card and using `d`shortcut, but I haven't found a way to do it in one step, either. Documentation doesn't mention any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done using [Butler](https://trello.com/power-ups/5935cab6b26816f9d49fd814/butler). There are different options you can use; the one I find most straightforward is `when I enter a card name ending with a date, set due on the date and remove the matched text`.

Another possibility could be `when I enter a card description containing a date (...)`.

[image: Screeshot of the Butler Trigger entry form]